# email etiquette from boss - capitalization

Tags: professionalism, management, email

Maybe times have changed or the new norm is to not capitalize anything in a sentence, but ...

I have 2 superiors:

- one takes the time to say hello, ask/please/thank you in their email when requesting things.
- the new superior does not feel the need to address anyone in their email while not bothering with capitalization or something not bothering with spelling.

Is this style of writing new? The heading, the sentences are all in lower case. 
Their name is capitalized.

Comment: Let me ask you this: what will you do when someone answers what you have asked? "Yes, it is new, this is how it is now" or "No, that's not new, nobody else does that." How will such answers help you. I recommend you ask your real question, which I think is *"should I be offended that my new superior can't even bother to type properly to me, especially when asking me to do things?"* But until you ask your real question, who can answer you?

Comment: Incidentally your heading is all lower case too.

Comment: "Maybe times have changed or the new norm is to not capitalize anything in a sentence" - No, it's not the "new norm", it's probably just the lazy way. For example, when you write in a chat room, you usually don't bother with such details as capitalization or punctuation. Or when using SMS on a phone, etc. When you're the boss, you probably get to ignore such details too.

Comment: @eirikdaude What a freaking hypocrite.  I vote to close.

Comment: I would argue it could be a matter of personal style. In a smaller office or with people who work close together, your supervisor may choose to just skip the formalities and get to the point - much like a conversation or an instant message. If department-wide or company-wide emails are being sent out with bad spelling/punctuation, then I would agree that laziness is the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Some people are just very poor at expressing themselves in writing, others are simply indifferent (to put it kindly).

It's very likely that this person is simply lazy and/or ignorant.

So, ***no***, it's not a "new" style of writing - neither is writing without capitalizing any letters, or ignoring punctuation, etc.

Whatever style these other people may be using, your best bet is to be professional: use proper grammar and punctuation, and always be polite (use proper greetings, etc)